# Converse of the projection theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to prove the converse of the projection theorem:
If for every $f\in H$ there is a $p\in M$ such that $\|p−f\|=\inf\limits_{v\in M}\|v−f\|$, then $M$ is closed.

Is my proof correct?

Let $p_n\in M,n=1,2,\ldots,$ be a sequence converging to $g\in H$. Then there is a $p\in M$ such that $\|p−g\|=\inf\limits_{v\in M}\|v−g\|$, so $\|p−g\|\leq \|p_n-g\|\,$  for all $n$. Now as $n$ goes to infinity the RHS goes to zero, so $g=p\in M$. Therefore, $M$ contains all its limit points and is closed.

Comment: Your argument is correct (even in more general *metric* spaces instead of Hilbert space).